# Can I terminate the depth of a query in a TFS ItemSpec string?

Tags: c#, tfs

```
ItemSpec spec = new ItemSpec(string.Format(@"$\{0}\Folder\{1}", project, branch), RecursionType.Full);
```

Now what I want to do is stop the query at "branch".  Is this possible?  How do I prevent it from returning all subfolders without string manipulation and if checks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to query for all items in `branch`?  Just use `RecursionType.None`.  When you pass the following `ItemSpec` to `GetItems`:

```
new ItemSpec(String.Format(@"$/{0}/Folder/{1}", project, branch), RecursionType.None);
```

You will be returned only the items directly in the `branch` folder, excluding children.